# showing an extra string while reading a file in c++ using fstream

Tags: c++, error-handling, ifstream

I have a program in c++ which is used to read some text from a .txt file using fstream functions. But on output screen, it is showing an extra output of while loop which is undesirable.So if tt.txt contains the data

```
ss 
123
```

then output is

```
Name ss
roll no 123

name
roll 123
```

Code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void student_read()
{
  clrscr();
  char name[30];
  int i,roll_no;
  ifstream fin("tt.txt",ios::in,ios::beg);
  if(!fin)
  {
    cout<<"cannot open for read ";
    return;
  }

  while(!fin.eof())
  {  
    fin>>name;
    cout<<endl;
    fin>>roll_no;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Name is"<<"\t"<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Roll No is"<<roll_no<<   endl;
  }
}

void main()
{
  clrscr();
  cout<<"Students details is"<<"\n";
  student_read();
  getch();
}
```

Comment: You are missing the closing bracket for the while loop in student_read() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the C++ FAQ for help with I/O: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/input-output.html

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void student_read() {
  char name[30];
  int roll_no;

  std::ifstream fin("tt.txt");
  if (!fin) {
    std::cout << "cannot open for read ";
    return;
  }

  while(fin >> name >> roll_no) {
    std::cout << "Name is\t" << name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Roll No is\t" << roll_no << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Students details is\n";
  student_read();
}
```

Comment: Is there FAQ on how to properly input from istream? This mistake is asked every day.

Comment: Error in Turbo c++ :-  1. Type qualifier std must be a class or struct name.    2. int main should return a value

Comment: The critical difference is `while(fin >> name >> roll_no)`.